# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement - Table "USER_DETAIL" not found; SQL statement:

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm getting error mentioned in title while calling User login() method. UserDetail Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_detail")
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = NamedQueryConstants.USER_FIND_ALL, query = "SELECT u FROM UserDetail u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = NamedQueryConstants.USER_FIND_BY_USER_NAME, query = "SELECT u FROM UserDetail u WHERE u.userName = ?1") })
public class UserDetail implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;

private String password;

@Column(name = "user_email_id")
private String userEmailId;

@Column(name = "user_name")
private String userName;
```

Below is StackTrace :

> 2019-01-21 02:12:37 INFO  stdout:71 - Hibernate: select userdetail0_.user_id as user_id1_21_, userdetail0_.last_activity_date as last_act2_21_, userdetail0_.online_status as online_s3_21_, userdetail0_.password_change_date as password4_21_, userdetail0_.password as password5_21_, userdetail0_.user_email_id as user_ema6_21_, userdetail0_.user_name as user_nam7_21_ from user_detail userdetail0_ where userdetail0_.user_name=?
>
> 02:12:38,036 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-4) SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02
>
> 02:12:38,037 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-4) Table "USER_DETAIL" not found; SQL statement:
>
> select userdetail0_.user_id as user_id1_21_, userdetail0_.last_activity_date as last_act2_21_, userdetail0_.online_status as online_s3_21_, userdetail0_.password_change_date as password4_21_, userdetail0_.password as password5_21_, userdetail0_.user_email_id as user_ema6_21_, userdetail0_.user_name as user_nam7_21_ from user_detail userdetail0_ where userdetail0_.user_name=? [42102-193]
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:38 INFO  stdout:71 - Persistence exception# occured -
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:38 ERROR stderr:71 - javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:38 ERROR stderr:71 -    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:38 ERROR stderr:71 -    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:38 ERROR stderr:71 -    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:560)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:38 ERROR stderr:71 -    at com.itsys.erp.server.dal.impl.GenericJpaDAO.findSingleByProperty(GenericJpaDAO.java:251)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:38 ERROR stderr:71 -    at com.itsys.erp.server.commonservices.usermgmt.impl.UserManagementServiceImpl.checkUserCredentials(UserManagementServiceImpl.java:29)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:38 ERROR stderr:71 -    at com.itsys.erp.server.commonservices.usermgmt.slsbadapter.UserManagementServiceSlsb.checkUserCredentials(UserManagementServiceSlsb.java:39)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:38 ERROR stderr:71 -    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:38 ERROR stderr:71 -    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:38 ERROR stderr:71 -    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:38 ERROR stderr:71 -    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:38 ERROR stderr:71 -    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:38 ERROR stderr:71 -    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:38 ERROR stderr:71 -    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:38 ERROR stderr:71 -    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:90)
>
> ...
> ...
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:39 ERROR stderr:71 - Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:39 ERROR stderr:71 -    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:39 ERROR stderr:71 -    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:39 ERROR stderr:71 -    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:39 ERROR stderr:71 -    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:39 ERROR stderr:71 -    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
>
> .....
>
> 2019-01-21 02:12:39 ERROR stderr:71 -    ... 158 more

While I'm able to execute Junit tests successfully for above User login() JPQL query, still I'm getting above error when calling login() method from JSF.
I'm injecting EJB service in JSF and using Wildfly 11 App Server.
What could be the reason causing error ?

Comment: ..different (db) environments!? (the reason/error message is quite clear & speaking: there is no table "USER_DETAIL" in the database(... you are connected with))